# How to configure the Welcome Window?

Tags: front-end, customization, default

How to reduce and set a smaller size in the font/text in the Welcome Window?

I´d like to obtain in Mathematica 12.3 a Welcome Window as the on I have in Mathematica 11.3

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Edit > Preferences > Interface and set the Magnification level to 75%.